# Latex Counter custom reference formatting

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

Simple use case, I have a counter for requirements, R1, R2, etc like the one below:

```
\newcounter{requirementcounter}
\newcommand{\requirement}{\refstepcounter{requirementcounter}R.\therequirementcounter}
```

However, when I refer to a counter instance (i.e. `\requirement{req:a}` by `\ref{req:a}`) then the `\ref{}` will only contain the counter value, rather than the custom label in the format of R.value

How can I format the counter reference label?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your code provide a `\label` instruction for `req:a`?

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to redefine macro `\the<counter>`. Then the `\label`/`\ref` system will pick it up automatically:

```
\newcounter{requirementcounter}
\renewcommand*{\therequirementcounter}{R\arabic{requirementcounter}}

...
\refstepcounter{requirementcounter}\therequirementcounter
\label{req:a}
...
\ref{req:a}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small snippet that can do this:

```
\newcounter{reqcount}
\newcommand{\reqitem}[1]{%
  R\ref*{#1} \refstepcounter{reqcount}\label{#1}
}
\newcommand{\descref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{R\ref*{#1}}%
}
```

Example usage:

```
Here is req: \reqitem{reqi:a}

Here is req: \reqitem{reqi:b}

Here is reference: \descref{reqi:a}, \descref{reqi:a}, \descref{reqi:b}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to demonstrate with the duplicate `\descref{reqi:a}` directives?